# Invoking programs in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to bash and can't seem to get it to compile some C code without annoying messages. I'm quote sure it's the semicolons because if I remove or change them at all it will pretty much break. The warnings/errors I get are ": not found: :" with nothing else repeatedly for every line. Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
GCC=/usr/bin/gcc ;
INSERTS="10000 20000 50000 100000 150000 250000 375000 500000 750000 1000000"
CODESRC=./code.c;
#compile with options
$GCC -DDEBUG -o codetest $CODESRC;
#run with parameters
./codetest $INSERTS;
```

**edit:**

The code compiles and runs fine. If I remove all the semicolons and try to run it using `sh test.sh` I get the following.

```
test.sh: 6: /usr/bin/gcc
: not found
test.sh: 8: ./codetest: not found
```

**edit:**
Ahh, silly me; it was a windows/unix line endings problem, became apparent when running ./test.sh and getting `/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolons shouldn't be necessary, but other than that the script looks ok.

- Can you be more specific about the errors you're getting?
- Does the code compile and run correctly when you try it outside of the script?
- How are you running the script?

---

**Edit**

- As that definitely the location of gcc? What is the output of `which gcc`
- Are you running the script from the same directory as your code?
- Since your script specifies that it should be ran with `/bin/bash` you should run it as `./test.sh`, not `sh test.sh`